# Save as error excel while adding data to existing excel sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, save-as

I have a question regarding an error I have while using openpyxl. I want to save data to multiple excel sheets with a certain template using a loop. This is working fine if loop over 10 values. But when I want to loop over 100 files I have the following error message:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Methode SaveAs van klasse Workbook is mislukt.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

The part of the codes which gives occasionally an error is:

```
for row in test.index: 
    g = data.loc[row]
    app=xw.App(visible=False,add_book=False)
    app.display_alerts=False
    app.screen_updating=False
    filepath = 'output/'+ g.location +"_"+g.filename
    df = details_dict[g.filename]
    df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
    wb = app.books.open('Template3.xlsx')
    # Save the template under a new name for every row in data.index
    wb.save(filepath[:-4])
    # Look for the worksheet
    sht = wb.sheets['Blad1']
    # put value in specific cell
    sht.range('C12').value = merged.iloc[row,12]
    sht.range('C13').value = merged.iloc[row,13]
    sht.range('C14').value = merged.iloc[row,14]
    sht.range('C15').value = merged.iloc[row,15]
    sht.range('C16').value = merged.iloc[row,5]
    sht.range('C17').value = merged.iloc[row,6]
    sht.range('C18').value = merged.iloc[row,8]
    sht.range('C19').value = merged.iloc[row,7]
    sht.range('C20').value = merged.iloc[row,11]
    sht.range('A52').value = df
    sht.range('A52').options(pd.DataFrame, expand='table').value
    wb.close()
    app.quit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: The exception is coming from COM and therefore not openpyxl. I assume `xw` refers to Xlwings (this is one reason why aliasing is not a great idea) so you might want to check with that.

Comment: There is probably a problem with `filepath[:-4]`. Print it
out to see what it contains, then try the same action in Excel by hand. I suspect you are getting a popup asking you to confirm overwriting a file that already exists.